# Unable to set LinearLayout with margins programmatically

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

I wanted to have a two LinearLayouts and each separated with some margins. Below layout works perfectly.

```
<GridLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:columnCount="1">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/border_style">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="Uday"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/border_style">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="ABCD"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</GridLayout>
```

Now i want to do it programmatically as the textview values are dynamic and
i tried with ***setMargins*** of LayoutParameters, but didnt work. I tried below code in a loop, but i am not able to see the layouts separated with margins.

```
LinearLayout lLayour = new LinearLayout(getActivity());
lLayour.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
lLayour.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.border_style);
LinearLayout.LayoutParams llLP=new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
llLP.setMargins(5,5,5,5);
lLayour.setLayoutParams(llLP);

TextView tv=new TextView(getActivity());
tv.setText("1");
tv.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

lLayour.addView(tv);

gridLayout.addView(lLayour);
```

Later came to know that ***MarginLayoutParams***, but still didnt help:

```
LinearLayout lLayour = new LinearLayout(getActivity());
lLayour.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
lLayour.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.border_style);
LinearLayout.LayoutParams llLP=new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
lLayour.setLayoutParams(llLP);
setMargins(lLayour, 50, 50, 50, 50);

TextView tv=new TextView(getActivity());
tv.setText("1");
tv.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

lLayour.addView(tv);
gridLayout.addView(lLayour);

private void setMargins (View view, int left, int top, int right, int bottom) {
    if (view.getLayoutParams() instanceof LinearLayout.MarginLayoutParams) {
        LinearLayout.MarginLayoutParams p = (LinearLayout.MarginLayoutParams) view.getLayoutParams();
        p.setMargins(left, top, right, bottom);
        view.requestLayout();
    }
}
```

My border_style.xml file content is:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">
    <stroke android:width="2dp" android:color="#44aa77"/>
    <solid android:color="#ffffff" />
    <padding android:left="10dp" android:top="10dp" android:right="10dp" android:bottom="10dp"/>
</shape>
```

Answer (score 0):

As per the details mentioned, if `LinearLayout` is not taking margins, you can also try add `padding` instead of `margins`.

Following is the code to set padding to `LinearLayout` programmatically:

```
mLinearLayout.setPadding(20,20,20,20);
```